# Octopus Deploy: no matching targets were found

Tags: octopus-deploy

I'm using Octopus Deploy project with few steps.
In the first step "Enable Deployment Targets" I'm using Powershell script which enable deployment targets which are disabled at the moment of running of the first step "Enable Deployment Targets"

After 1st step all deployment targets in the given environment and channel are Healthy (green), but other steps are skipped with the message bellow:

Searched for targets:

- specifically matching these ids: (no id's provided)
- that are enabled
- with no id exclusions
- with no environment exclusions
- has a role that overlaps: Windows test and SQL test
- with no tenant exclusions
- with any health status

Info
Skipping this step as no matching targets were found

If I enable deployment targets manually and run other steps then the everything is ok and work properly

Any idea what can be the cause of this?

Comment: I resolve the issue with adding one more step "Health Check" after "Enable Deployment Targets" step.  After passing Health Check step successfully, Octopus realize that the target is online and all other steps are executed without issue.  Maybe this solution will help someone else with same issue :)

Comment: This is by design. What it the reason you are starting with the targets disabled?

Comment: I have disabled the Deployment target manually for testing purposes. In my deployment process I have added 2 steps using powershell scripts. First step is to enable deployment target and after that all other steps from the deployment process are executed. And the last step is powershell script to disable the deployment target. So actually with my next deployment I'm starting with disabled deployment target and because of that I need to implement step for enabling